# Please help me ID this bonsai?

Tags: identification, bonsai

I recently acquired this plant from a friend. I just need help identifying what type of bonsai/ plant this is.

[image: Unknown bonsai]

Comment: Why don't you ask your friend?

Comment: She doesn't know it either.

Comment: How long ago did your friend give this plant to you?

Comment: is it a bonsai?

Comment: It is a bonsai but needs some pruning and all that work. Mr. b.nota was kind enough in identifying the plant for me. it's a Buddhist Pine apparently and I'm kinda excited to work on it come spring time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is [*Podocarpus macrophyllus*](https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/all/podocarpus-macrophyllus-var-maki/), or Buhddist pine. This species is very suitable for bonsai. Try to keep your tree small, yours has large leafs now, but you would like to keep them small (by [pruning and shaping](https://www.bonsaiempire.com/basics/styling/pruning) it). ideally you would like to shape it into something like [this](http://www.bonsaiboy.com/catalog/product4740.html).

Does your tree get enough light? It is placed next to the window, right?

Comment: I think that might be it! Thank you, @b.nota! Appreciate it. All the while I thought it was of a bamboo-sort-of family. XD And, my tree is nothing like what you linked me. haha! I better start working on this one. Although, it's winter here in Canada, I might just let it do it's thing and work on it in Spring. I'm afraid I might kill it if I do the pruning this time of the month. Yes it's by the window and all my plants are in the basement. It's not direct sunlight but a very well lit basement during the day. Does it have to be in direct sunlight?

Comment: Yeah you can better wait for early spring before pruning the bonsai. In the mean time try to read about how to do this on the web, it can take years before you get a real tree-like shape into it. I think it will benefit from sunlight, especially when indoors, but now during winter it is not trivial (they need it to grow in spring and summer). Good luck with, I had a podocarpus bonsai indoor once, but it died, so take good care of it!

Comment: Thanks again! Yeah, come spring time, I'll work on them. I like gardening and all but it was not a serious hobby. I've always wanted to have something to do with bonsai but never really got into it. I had 2 Ginseng bonsai trees last year but they died too. It was my fault, I left my bedroom window open in my old apartment while I was gone for about a week and that was mid-November with below 0 (-C) temp. XD Well, lesson learned. I'm sure I'll enjoy this new hobby of mine and I'll definitely welcome all your expertise. Thanks again, Buddy! :D